# What is the ant-like thing that crawls into the queen's ear?

Tags: plot-explanation, versailles

I just finished watched [*Versailles*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3830558/) Season 3, Episode 4 "Crime and Punishment" on Netflix.

At around 37 minutes 50 seconds, a lady goes to get a bottle from a secret place where a man hands her the bottle. She gives him some money in a bag in return.  Then, around 46/50 minutes in, the same lady that had the bottle, sneaks to the king and queen's master bedroom, over to the pillow, and sprays it out underneath it.

Later on, if you go to 51 minutes and 20 seconds, you see that when the queen goes to sleep, an ant is crawling from the pillow to the queen's ear.

She gets sick, and later she dies.

My question is: what did the lady get from the man, and what kind of ant is it that got her sick and caused her death?

[image]

[image]

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyDYg.png)

[image]

Comment: An ant that was dipped in poison?  In Hamlet the king was allegedly killed by poison poured into his ear. But if an ear can't adsorb a fatal dose of poison and get it in the bloodstream, the "king's ghost" would have been a devil pretending to be the king's ghost and lying to trick Hamlet into killing for revenge and thus damning himself to hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Queen is killed off with a mysterios bug. It is called Triatoma infestans. They are commonly called kissing bug or barber bug in English and little blood suckers. They usually bite humans around the mouth and eyes, and usually at night. They can cause Changas disease. It starts mild, with possible fever and wollen lymph nodes, headches and were the bite occurred. Then cramps can follow, as well as stomach aches, redness of the eyes, diarrhea and difficulty in breathing. If not treated, It can kill you.

[image]

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/versailles_tv/comments/8h2sx4/s3ep45_question_spoilers/)

> It's almost certainly an assassin bug appropriately named :) . I don't
>   think they have poison but they do bite humans on soft tissue mouth
>   eyes etc. . And they can carry a nasty parasite which can kill...
>   Unlikely to go in the ear but adds to the horror :) .
>   http://khak.com/beware-of-this-insect-known-as-the-assassin-bug/ I've
>   only seen the scene with the bug by the way so possibly there's more
>   info now :S

[khak](https://khak.com/beware-of-this-insect-known-as-the-assassin-bug/)

[partylike1660](http://partylike1660.com/thoughts-on-versailles-the-queens-mysterious-ear-bug/)

Comment: So, the queen died because it killed her brain ?

Comment: The CDC says the most common complications are:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 Heart rhythm abnormalities that can cause sudden death
Dilate heart that doesn't pump blood well
Dilated esophagus or colon, leading to difficulties with eating or passing stool

Comment: So, the Queen probably died died of heart failure.